# For each element in list of lists, merge with corresponding value in a separate flat list

Tags: python, list

let's say I have two lists:

```
lst1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

```
lst2 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

And I want to combine both such that the output would look like:

```
output = [['ax', 'bx', 'cx'], ['ay', 'by', 'cy'], ['az', 'bz', 'cz']]
```

Can I do this with only list comprehension? Using `zip()` I tried the following line of code

```
output = [[x + y for x,y in zip(sublist, lst2)] for sublist in lst1]
```

but as expected it yielded `[['ax', 'by', 'cz'], ['ax', 'by', 'cz'], ['ax', 'by', 'cz']]`. I am trying to build on this line of code to get my desired output. but not sure where to go from here.

I am thinking that I may need to access the indices in lst2 using `enumerate()` so that I can apply only the strings in `lst2[0]` to the first sublist, then`lst2[1]` to the second sublist, etc etc. Can this be done with list comprehension?

Comment: You're so close, I'm actually confident you can do this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution you can give it a try,

```
lst1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
lst2 = ['x', 'y', 'z']

print(
    [[ii + j for ii in i] for i, j in zip(lst1, lst2)]
)
```

---

```
[['ax', 'bx', 'cx'], ['ay', 'by', 'cy'], ['az', 'bz', 'cz']]
```